# It does not show a white rectangle area when I save selected portions of the image in the below code

Tags: image, file, save, crop

[I want to hide some area from selected portion by adding rectangle but it not showing when i save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkpRW.jpg),[this the saved image you can see here the portion not contain white rectangle box, which i need to hide content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnfWg.png)
In this code, I try to save some portions from an image as an image in a folder and database by sending area coordinates and portions and converting the base64 string to a PHP file that handles the rest of the functionality. The problem is that after selecting some portions, I want to hide some content from selecting portions, but when i draw rectangle to hide that portion on the selected part, it does not display after saving the portion in the image folder. Please guide me on how to achieve this functionality.

`

Save Selected Areas
Toggle Rectangle

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var jcropApi;
        var selectedAreas = []; // Array to store selected areas
        var isRectangleMode = false; // Flag to indicate whether rectangle mode is active

        // Initialize Jcrop with multi selection enabled
        jQuery('#selectableImage').Jcrop({
            multi: true,
            onSelect: function (coords) {
                // Check if rectangle mode is active
                if (isRectangleMode) {
                    // Draw a white rectangle
                    drawOverlay(coords, 'white-rectangle');
                } else {
                    // Handle selection
                    selectedAreas.push(coords);
                    console.log('Selected areas:', selectedAreas);

                    // Draw an overlay for the selected area
                    drawOverlay(coords, 'jcrop-selection');
                }
            }
        }, function () {
            jcropApi = this;
        });

        // Save selected areas when the button is clicked
        jQuery('#saveAreas').on('click', function () {
            // Check if any area is selected
            if (selectedAreas.length === 0) {
                alert('No areas selected!');
                return;
            }

           // Create an array to store base64 strings and area information for each area
           var dataToSend = [];
            var mainImage = jQuery('#selectableImage').attr('src').split('/').pop();
            // Process each selected area
            for (var i = 0; i < selectedAreas.length; i++) {
                var area = selectedAreas[i];

                // Create a canvas for each selected area
                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                // Load the image
                var image = new Image();
                image.src = jQuery('#selectableImage').attr('src');

                // Set canvas dimensions to match the selected area
                canvas.width = area.w;
                canvas.height = area.h;

                // Draw the selected area on the canvas
                ctx.drawImage(image, area.x, area.y, area.w, area.h, 0, 0, area.w, area.h);

                // Convert canvas content to base64 string
                var base64String = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

                // Store base64 string and area information in an object
                var areaData = {
                    base64String: base64String,
                    area: area,
                    mainImg:mainImage
                };

                // Push the object to the data array
                dataToSend.push(areaData);
            }

            // Send all base64 strings and area information to the server
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/snap-news/save.php',
                contentType: 'application/json', // Set content type to JSON
                data: JSON.stringify({ areas: dataToSend }), // Convert data to JSON string
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    alert('Selected areas saved successfully!');
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                    alert('Error saving selected areas!');
                }
            });
        });

        // Toggle rectangle mode when the button is clicked
        jQuery('#toggleRectangle').on('click', function () {
            isRectangleMode = !isRectangleMode;
            console.log('Rectangle mode:', isRectangleMode);
        });

        function drawOverlay(coords, className) {
            // Create a new div for the overlay
            var overlay = document.createElement('div');
            overlay.className = className;
            overlay.style.position = 'absolute';
            overlay.style.left = coords.x + 'px';
            overlay.style.top = coords.y + 'px';
            overlay.style.width = coords.w + 'px';
            overlay.style.height = coords.h + 'px';

            // Append the overlay to the container
            jQuery('#selectableImage').parent().append(overlay);
        }
    });
</script>
```

`